# python importError while importing cv2

Tags: python, opencv, homebrew

I have installed opencv3 using brew, but am facing `importError` while executing `import cv2`

```
>>> import cv2
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>

ImportError: dlopen(/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cv2.so, 2): Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/libpng/lib/libpng16.16.dylib

  Referenced from: /usr/local/Cellar/opencv/2.4.12_2/lib/libopencv_highgui.2.4.dylib
  Reason: Incompatible library version: libopencv_highgui.2.4.dylib requires version 37.0.0 or later, but libpng16.16.dylib provides version 35.0.0
```

Can someone help ?

Comment: Did you try upgrading your libpng?

Comment: Yes, still the issue remains

Comment: Where is the newest libpng located? Is it `/usr/local/opt/libpng/lib/libpng16.16.dylib` or some other place? Maybe you have two versions and it find the wrong one.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The following resolved the problem.

```
brew uninstall --force brew-cask
brew uninstall --force opencv
brew doctor
brew tap homebrew/science
brew install opencv
```